# CSS selector for first image, only if first child

Tags: css, css-selectors

Does anyone know if it's possible to define a CSS selector that selects the first image within a div, but only if it's the first child within the div.

In jQuery I would use a comparison something like this...

```
if ($('#div img:first-child') == $('#div>*:first-child')) {
  ...
}
```

Comment: That's not how you compare the results of two jQuery selectors. You need to use [`.is()`](http://api.jquery.com/is) instead.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

[By definition of "first-child"](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#first-child), the selector (assuming your `div` had an `id` of `div`)

```
#div img:first-child
```

already does that. First image of any `div` is

```
div img:first-child
```

However, as BoltClock's answer points out, the child selector is needed if you may have `img` elements nested deeper in the `div`.

Answer (score 14):

You don't need to do a comparison in jQuery if all you want to do is select that `img`. Just combine your two selectors like so:

```
#div > img:first-child
```

This works in both jQuery and CSS.

Comment: True, the child selector would be needed if there may be other nested `div` elements.

Comment: Or, for that matter, any other nested elements that `img` might be first child of under the `div`.

Answer (score 3):

It's a simple CSS selector:

```
#div:first-child img:first-child
```

Comment: This only works if `#div` itself is the first child of its parent, which isn't mentioned anywhere in the question.